# Angular Material ( mat-chip-list cutted if height of block is big ). The only on Android

Tags: android, angularjs, angular, mobile, angular-material

```
      <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="80" fxFlex.sm="100">
        <div *ngFor="let perm of arrayOFobjectPermissions; let z = index" class="permissions-list">
          <mat-card  [title]="perm.type" class="card-permissions-role" >
            <mat-card-header>

              <mat-card-title>{{ perm.type }}</mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-chip-list [multiple]="true" >
              <mat-chip *ngFor="let permissionsNames of perm.res; let i = index"
                        selected="{{ !outlined[z][i] }}"
                        (click)="addRole(z, i, permissionsNames.name)"
                        [value]="permissionsNames.name"
                        [selectable]="true" style="cursor: pointer">
                {{ permissionsNames.name }}
              </mat-chip>
            </mat-chip-list>
          </mat-card>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The occurred if size of  mat-chip-list blocks bigger then 700px about.
On Android in all mobile versions.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QxGQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QxGQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

By default material mat-card set to own style. **That was the reason.**

> overflow: hidden;

Need change to -->*overflow: visible;*
in scss file for mat-card.